# Swift & Firebase Auth check in App Delegate?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am having a hard time finding a clear answer on this.

Currently I have my Firebase auth check happening in my login view controller which is my apps initial view (code below). It works fine but doesn't seem like the best pattern. For one, when the app boots up you get a flicker of the login screen before the segue on successful auth.

My question - it seems like the best place for this would be in App Delegate for an auth check? No amount of googling makes me believe this is the common pattern though.

Any advice is super appreciated.

```
var handle: AuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle?

//----- init, lifecycle & auth ----//
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    handle = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { (auth, user) in
        if((user) != nil){
            print("logged in as: " + user!.uid)
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "LoginSegue", sender: self)
        }else{
            print("Not Logged in")
        }

    }
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    Auth.auth().removeStateDidChangeListener(handle!)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In AppDelegate 's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` put this at beginning after firebase.config

```
self.window?.addSubview(loadingView) // set tag for it
handle = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { (auth, user) in
 // here remove loadingView
  if((user) != nil){
       let vc = // homeVC
       self.window?.rootViewController = vc
  }else{
      print("Not Logged in")
       let vc = // Login
       self.window?.rootViewController = vc
  }

}
```